# Why wouldn't Latex balance my columns on *all pages* (acmart document class)

Tags: spacing, two-column, acm, acmart

We wrote a document using the acmart document class (double column).

On most pages, the two columns are balanced. However, in some places there are 2-5 lines difference between the two columns of a page.

> **Is there a way to force Latex to have same column lengths on every page of the document?**

> Ideally, I'd want the spacing between lines on the shorter column to increase slightly so that the columns will have exactly lengths.

To create an MWE, I shortened the document a lot, and this is not as severe as in some places, but sill bothers me:
[image]

Code:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{warn}{textcomp}
\documentclass[sigconf,9pt]{acmart}

\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\newcommand{\sys}{\ensuremath{\mathit{AAAA}}\xspace}


\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\acmPrice{}



\copyrightyear{2020}
\acmYear{2020}
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}\acmConference[Aaaaaaaaaaaaa '20]{aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aa aaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaaa, aaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa}{aaaaaa 10--14, 2020}{aaaaaaa aaaaa, aa, aaa}
\acmBooktitle{Annual conference of the aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaaa, aaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa (aaaaaaa '20), aaaaaa 10--14, 2020, aaaaaaa aaaaa, aa, aaa}
\acmPrice{15.00}
\acmDOI{aa.aaaa/aaaaaaa.aaaaaaa}
\acmISBN{aaa-a-aaaa-aaaa-a/aa/aa}


\ccsdesc[500]{aaaaaaaaaaaaa~Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa}
\ccsdesc[500]{aaaaaaaaaaaaa~Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa}
\ccsdesc[500]{aaaaaaaaaaaaa~Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa}

\begin{document}
\title{\sys: aaaa aaaa-aaaa aaaa aaaa}
\author{aaaa aaaa}
\affiliation{%
\institution{aaaa University}
}
\email{aaaa@aaaa.aaaa.edu}
\author{aaaa aaaa}
%\authornote{The secretary disavows any knowledge of this author's actions.}
\affiliation{%
\institution{University of aaaa aaaa}
}
\email{aaaa@aaaa.edu}
\author{aaaa aaaa}
\affiliation{%
\institution{aaaa University}
}
\email{aaaa@aaaa.aaaa.edu}
\author{aaaa aaaa}
\affiliation{%
\institution{aaaa aaaa University aaaa aaaa}
}
\email{aaaa.aaaa@aaaa.ac.uk}

% \email{email@domain.com}

% The default list of authors is too long for headers}
\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{AAA AAAAA et al.}

\begin{abstract}
aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aa-aaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaaa a aaaa aaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa, aaa aaaa aaaaaaa. aaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaa {aaaaaaaaaaa-aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa.}

aaaaaaaaa aaa, aa aa-aaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaaa aaaaaa. AAAA aaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaaa aaa-aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaa aa aa aaa aa aaa aaa. 
aa aaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa, 
aaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa. 
aaa aa aaaaaaaaaaa aa a4 aaa aaa aa aaaaaa aa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa.
aaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa,
{aa aaaa aaaa aaa 
aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaa aaaaaaa, aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaa,} aaaaa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaa aaaaaa, aaaa {aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaa aa aaa aaa.}
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaa aaa a aaaaaaa aa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaa aa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa~\cite{aaaaaaaaa}, aaaaaaaaa~\cite{aaaaa}, aaaaa 
aaaaaaaaaaaa~\cite{aaaaaaaaaaaaa}, aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa~\cite{aaaaaaaaaa}, 
aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa~\cite{aaaaaaaa,aaaaaaaaa}, aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa~\cite{aaaa}, aaaa 
aaaaaaaaa~\cite{aaaaaaaaaa,aaaaaaa,aaaaaaa}, aaaa aaaaaaa~\cite{aaaaa}, aaa aaaa 
aaaaaaa~\cite{aaaaaaaaaaa}. 
a aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa aa aaa aa-aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa (aaa)~\cite{aaa}. 
aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaa aaaaaa,
aaaa aa aaaaaa aa, aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa, aa aaaaa aaaaaa, aa aa aaaaaa aa. aaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaa aaaaaaaaa  %(aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa) 
aa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaaa.  

aaa aa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaa (aaaa)~\cite{aaaaaaaa-aaa,aaaaaaaa-aaa,aaaaaaaaa-aaa,aaaaaa-aaa}, aaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaa-aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa~\cite{aaa-aaa,aaaa}.
a aaa aaaaaaaa aa aaa aa aaa aaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaa. aaaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaaa, aaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaa aaa aaaa aaaaaa.
aaaaaaaa, aaa aaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaa-aaaaaa, aaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aa: aa a aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaa a aaaa, aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aa aaaaa aa aaaaaaaa, aa a.a\% aa a aaaa aaaaa aaaaaa.
aaaa aa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaa aa aaa aaa aaaaaaaa~\cite{aaa}, aaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa a aaaaa aaa aaa, aaa aaa aaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa a aaaaa. 
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa, aaaaa aaaa aaa aa aaaa aa aaaaa aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa (aaa). 
aa a aaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaa aa aaaaa a aaaaaaa, a.a., aa aaa aaaa, aaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaa aa aaaaaa aa aaaaaaa aaa aaa-aa-aaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaa aaaa~\cite{aaaaaaaaaa}. 
{aaaaaa, aaa aaaaaaaa aa aaa aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aa aaaa aaaaa aa a aa\% aaaaaaaa aaa aa\% aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaa aaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaa (\S\ref{aaaa}).
aaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa at aaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaa (\S\ref{aaaa:aaaa}).}

aa aaaaa aaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aa aa-aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa, 
aaa aa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaa;  aa aaaaaaaaaa, aa aaaa aa 
aaaaaaaa aaa aaa-aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa.  
aa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aa-aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa (\sys), a aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aa aaa, aaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aa aaa 
aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaa-aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaa aaa
aa aaa aaaa. 
{\sys aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaa aa aa aa aaa aa aaa aaa, aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aa aaaa aa. aa aaaaa aaaa aaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa. aaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaa-aaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaa~\cite{aaaa} aaa aa aaaaa aa aaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa, aa aa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaa aaaaa.}
aa aaaa aaa aaaaa, a aaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa. aaaa \sys, a aaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaa aaaa a aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aa aaaa aaaaaa. aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aa aaaa a \cite{aaaaaaaaaa} aa a aaaa'a aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaa. 
aa a aaaaaaaa, aaaaa aaaa aaa a aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaa aa aaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaa, \sys aaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aa aa aaaaaaaa aaa aaa-aaaaaa aaaaaaaa. aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaa aa aaaa, 
aaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa, aa aa aaa aaaaaaaa aa aaaa aaa aa aaa aaa-aaaaaa-aaa-aaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaa aaaaaaaa. 
%
{aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa. aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaa, aaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa. \sys aa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa}
%
aaa aaaaaaa, aa aa aaaaaaaa aa aaaaa a aaaa'a aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa~\cite{aaaaaaaaaa,aaaaaaaaa,aaaaaaaaaa}, aa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaa aaaa a aaaaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaa. aaaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aa aaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaa aa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aa aaa, a.a., aaaa~\cite{aaaa}, aaaaa~\cite{aaaaaaa} aaa aaaa aa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaa'a aaaaaaaaaa, aaa aa aaa \mbox{aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaa.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: not sure why it fails exactly but it does warn you Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active

Comment: I'm not sure what this means, is there a way to avoid it?@DavidCarlisle

Comment: "occurred while output is active" means that tex failed to make a column of the specified height (for some reason) sorry balance is very old and acmart is a journal supported and somewhat complicated class, I'd take it up with the publisher.